# How to edit this map?

Tags: line

[image: Line map]

I wanted to make a similar line graph as below, but I just want to replace the letters and numbers with words. Is there a possible way?

[Simple line with dots, known coordinates](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34631/simple-line-with-dots-known-coordinates)

This is the original code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \path[draw, thick, -] (-.3,0) -- (3.3,0);
    \foreach \x in {0,...,3}{
        \path[draw, thick] (\x,0) -- ++(0,-.15) node [below] {\x};
    }
    \foreach \x/\name in {0/A,.5/B,1/C,1}{
        \path[draw, fill=blue] (\x,0) circle[radius=2pt] node [above=2 mm, blue] {\name};
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I tried editing the `0` in `\foreach \x/\name in {0/A,.5/B,1/C,1}` to a word, but Latex failed to compile it.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It would be much easier if you posted the link to that code (or even the code itself) instead of a screenshot of it.

Comment: What problems do you have when you modify the given code. Please show your effort.

Comment: And please provide a minimal working example, i.e. some code that works, shows what you have tried, and others can play with.

Comment: It is because `\x` is used as coordinates in `(\x,0)` so should be number. What you need is to insert a 3rd variable to store the text you want.

Answer (score 1):

Just replace letters and numbers with words. For placement words you can define new counters or define combination `\x/\name` where `\x` is distance on arrow. For example as I do in the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \noindent
    \begin{tikzpicture}[x=15mm]
        \path[draw, thick, ->] (-.3,0) -- (6.3,0);
        \foreach \i [count=\x] in {an, ban, pet, podgan, štiri, miši}%
        {
            \draw[thick] (\x,0) -- ++(0,-.15) 
                 node [text height=1.5ex, text depth=0.5ex, anchor=north] {\i};
        }
        \foreach \x/\name in {0/word, .6/word, 1/word,  1.5/word,2/word,
                              2.3/word,3/word, 3.3/word,4/word,  4.6/word,
                              5/word,  5.5/word, 6/word}%
        {
            \draw[fill=blue] (\x,0) circle[radius=2pt]
                node [above=2 mm, blue, anchor=west, rotate=45] {\name};
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Do I understood you question correctly?